# SICP: Why does process-forget-value call process-new-value?

Tags: scheme, lisp, constraints, sicp

This code is from SICP, [3.3.5 Propagation of Constraints](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%25_sec_3.3.5).  I can't seem to figure out why `process-forget-value` needs to call `process-new-value` as the final step.

The text says, *"The reason for this last step is that one or more connectors may still have a value (that is, a connector may have had a value that was not originally set by the adder), and these values may need to be propagated back through the adder."*

What is the simplest constraint network that can demonstrate why `(process-new-value)` is needed? Thanks!

```
(define (adder a1 a2 sum)
  (define (process-new-value)
    (cond ((and (has-value? a1) (has-value? a2))
           (set-value! sum
                       (+ (get-value a1) (get-value a2))
                       me))
          ((and (has-value? a1) (has-value? sum))
           (set-value! a2
                       (- (get-value sum) (get-value a1))
                       me))
          ((and (has-value? a2) (has-value? sum))
           (set-value! a1
                       (- (get-value sum) (get-value a2))
                       me))))

  (define (process-forget-value)
    (forget-value! sum me)
    (forget-value! a1 me)
    (forget-value! a2 me)
    (process-new-value))  ;;; * WHY * ???

  (define (me request)
    (cond ((eq? request 'I-have-a-value)  
           (process-new-value))
          ((eq? request 'I-lost-my-value) 
           (process-forget-value))
          (else 
           (error "Unknown request -- ADDER" request))))

  (connect a1 me)
  (connect a2 me)
  (connect sum me)
  me)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Is a test I have made removing `process-new-value` from the adder. You will see that the behavior is different.

```
(define c (make-connector))
(define a (make-connector))
(define b (make-connector))
(define d (make-connector))

(constant 10 a)
(constant 10 c)
(constant 10 d)

(define adder1 (adder a b c))
(define adder2 (adder a b d))

> (has-value? b)
#t

> (get-value b)
0

> (forget-value! b adder1)
'done    

> (has-value? b)
#f
```

If you do this with the correct version.

```
> (has-value? b)
#t
```

The second time also. As they say, when `adder1` tells `b` to forget its value. `a` and `c` being constants will still have a value, and the last `process-new-value` in `adder2`, will again set `b` to 0. This will also work if you use `set-value!` for `a` and `c`.